# r data.table selecting rows on condition

Tags: r, data.table, conditional-statements, subset, lapply

I have a data.table like this

```
library(data.table)
cells <- c(100, 1, 1980, 1, 0, 1,1,0,1, 150, 1 , 1980, 1,1,1,0,0,0,99,1,1980,1,1,1,1,0,0,899,1,1980,0,1,0,1,1,1 )
colname <- c("number","sex", "birthy", "2004","2005", "2006", "2007", "2008", "2009")
rowname <- c("1","2","3","4")
y <- matrix(cells, nrow=4, ncol=9, byrow=TRUE, dimnames = list(rowname,colname))
y <- data.table(y, keep.rownames = TRUE)
```

The value 1 in the column 2004 means that this person is continuous insured during the year 2004. Person being insured for 3 preceding years can be part of the study.
I need a subset of this data.table containing all observation where the following condition is true:
2004+2005+2006 = 3 or 2005+2006+2007 = or 2006+2007+...

To solve this I wrote a function and wanted to apply this function with lappy, stepping through all years up until the last possible sequence.
In reality start year and end year and also the minimal length of sequence can vary

```
years <- function(year, DTbl) {
  DTbl[sum(year:as.numeric(year+2))==3,]
}

by <- 2004 # study start
ey <- 2009 # study end
len <- 2007 # maximal begin of sequence to be tested
jahre <-3
DTpy <- data.table::rbindlist(lapply(by:len, years, DTbl=y))
```

Apparently this does not work, but also this

```
test <- y[ y[, 2006==1], vnew := "ok"]
```

is never true.

After spending a lot of time looking for some answers here I decided to post this question. I am still learning R and I appreciate your input on this issue.

Thanks
Alina

Comment: Fyi, because 2006 can also be read as a number, you can use backticks to indicate the column, `y[\`2006\`==1]`.

Comment: ok, so backsticks are used to different a variable name that could also be read as a number. Thank you Frank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to transform the data from wide to long format. In long format, the `rle()` function can be used to identify a sequence of 3 or more subsequent years:

```
tmp <- melt(y, id = "rn", measure.vars = patterns("^20"), 
            variable.factor = FALSE, variable.name = "year")[
              , rle(value), by = rn][values == 1, which(max(lengths) >= 3), by = rn]$rn
tmp
```

> ```
> [1] "2" "3" "4"
> ```

These are the row ids which fullfil the condition. These can be used to subset `y`:

```
y[as.integer(tmp)]
```

> ```
>    rn number sex birthy 2004 2005 2006 2007 2008 2009
> 1:  2    150   1   1980    1    1    1    0    0    0
> 2:  3     99   1   1980    1    1    1    1    0    0
> 3:  4    899   1   1980    0    1    0    1    1    1
> ```

Comment: For one fewer `by=rn`, there's `m[, with(rle(value), any(values == 1 & lengths >= 3)), by = rn]` and I guess you don't need to convert year to int unless the melted table m is being kept around / assigned somewhere.

Comment: @Frank, you are right, The `as.integer(year)` is an artefact from another approach which involved `diff(year)`

Comment: Thank you both so much, this is great!

Comment: This solution works smoothly. Now, I need to convert all 1 to 0, if they are not part of subsequent group. For example rn==4, the variable "2005" needs to be set to zero. Any suggestion?

Comment: @AlinaLudewig. I think there will be a solution based on `rle(value)`. However, this is a different problem, so post a new question, please.